# Vue loses slot reactivity when use with render function

Tags: vue.js

I have this markup

```html
    <ComponentA>
       <Child @click="selected=1">{{selected}}</Child>
       <Child @click="selected=2">{{selected}}</Child>
       <Child @click="selected=3">{{selected}}</Child>
       <Child @click="selected=4">{{selected}}</Child>
    </ComponentA>
```

```js
  data() {
    return: {selected: -1}
  }
```

Thats Ok, it's reactive and it shows `selected in -1` and if any `Child` is clicked, `selected` is changed and showed in Dom. But I need a way to mount just a slice of `Child` based on certains conditions. So my approach was as I show next:

```html
<!-- ComponentA -->
<template>
 <div id="container">
   <slot></slot>
 </div>
</template>
```

```js
function selectChildren(VNodes) {...} // return VNode[]
function mountSelectionChildren(VNodes) {
  const childrenCmp = {
    data: function () {
     return {
      items: [],
     }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.items = selectChildren(VNodes) // get a slice of total Child, based on certains conditions I ommited
    }
    render(h) {
      return h("div", [this.items.map(item => h("div", {...},[item]))])
    }
  }
  new Vue(childrenCmp).$mount("#container") 
}
export default {
  mounted() {
    mountSelectionChildren(this.$slots.default)
  }
}
```

It works, rendering the DOM and UI that I want, but now, click `Child` elems is not reactive and don't show `selected` attribute. So, how can I make slot mounted with render fn, becomes reactive?

Comment: this.items.map in plain JavaScript will return a new array - so I think that's where you're losing reactivity?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```js
function selectChildren(VNodes) {...} // return VNode[]

export default {
  render(h){
    let VNodes = this.$slots.default || []

    let items = selectChildren(VNodes)
    return h("div", [items.map(item => h("div", {...},[item]))])
  }
}
```